# Strange issue with Bitmap transparency while saving as BLOB

Tags: android, bitmap, blob

Trapped in a strange issue with Bitmap transparency, I have images with me and convert it in Blob and stored it in local Database.

I have this image

[image]

after storing it as Blob and fetching it, then image background gets filled

[image]

Any idea why this is happening, and to get through with it.

Thanks.

This is how i convert to Byte and stored to database

```
public byte[] BitmapToByte(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        return b;
    }
```

This is how i m fetching Blob as Bitmap from database

`mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length));` //blob by cursor

Comment: is this some kind of listview/gridview?

Comment: it is a gridview with baseadapter.

Comment: hmmm i'm not sure but did you tried this http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html

Comment: [Take a look](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/insert-image-to-database/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution, it is cause of using Android's Thumbnail folder(which creates additional preview and me passing thumbnail cursor to the image adapter). When i fetch image directly from the Database it is coming transparent.

Comment: hi sir can you show your code in your answer..that might help me as a beginner.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

My problem fixed just change the

> Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG  to  Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG

```
 public byte[] BitmapToByte(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
            //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, 100, baos); //origin
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); //fixed

            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            return b;
        }
```